# How to create a custom exception which wraps mutliple exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception, custom-exceptions

How to create a custom exception which wraps three different exceptions like `InvalidContextException`, `IllegalArgumentException`. For example, let's say there is a method:

```
public void method() throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, 
InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
      //Body of the method
}
```

I want to minimize the number of exceptions after throws keyword by creating a custom exception which handles `InstantiationException` and `IllegalAccessException` and `IllegalArgumentException` together as mentioned below:

```
 public void method() throws IOException, CustomException {
       //Body of the method
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Nikolas, wrapping exceptions is useful when you want to more generalize the exception or make it more specific. It's also useful to convert a checked exception to unchecked.

Comment: not thrilled with the proliferation of the number of exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the spirit of the question as asked:

You would have to catch the various exceptions within your method, and then throw a `CustomException` from your `catch` block.  The ability for an exception to "wrap" around another exception is built in via the `Exception` class itself (see the `Exception(Throwable cause)` constructor).

```
public void method() throws IOException, CustomException {
    try {
        //Body of the method
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e);
    }
}
```

That said, `IllegalArgumentException` is not a checked exception, so you wouldn't have to declare it anyway.

Also worth pointing out, the above is based on you specifying that you want to create a custom exception.  Another option is to declare in your `throws` clause some type that is a common base class of the various checked exceptions that might actually be thrown.  For example, both of the checked exceptions in your list are subclasses of `ReflectiveOperationException`, so you could just say

```
public void method() throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException {
    //Body of the method
}
```

The trade-off, of course, is that you're not being as informative to those writing code that calls your method, so that may limit the quality of their exception handlers.  In the extreme, you *could* just say `throws Thorwable`, but this is pretty poor form.

Comment: Thank you ! Cant  this be done with out using try catch in side body again. Isn't there a way when CustomException is thrown, the CustomException takes care of these exception internally?

Comment: @JamesKristen - Again returning to the literal question as asked: no, if it could I wouldn't have said "you would have to catch the various exceptions and...".  However, as I also pointed out, by stepping away from your prescribed approach of defining your own custom exception class, you do (at least sometimes) have other options.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `CustomException` class that declares only constructors with these specific classes.
In this way it can only wrapped these exceptions and not any other.

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException{

    public CustomException(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public CustomException(IllegalAccessException  e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public CustomException(InstantiationException e) {
        super(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: This could all be simplified by having a single constructor accepting `Throwable`

Comment: Yes but it would mean that `CustomException` could contain other exceptions such as RuntimeException or any other.

Comment: But does it really matter what exception it can wrap? It's all functionally the same.

Comment: It depends on the use case. For example if you want to handle only these exceptions in a specific way you don't want to catch any exception in CustomException

Answer (score 1):

You can catch each of the thrown exception and rethrow it in the custom exception:

```
...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
    throw new CustomException(ex);
}
```

The constructor of `CustomException` would take any exception as an argument and reformulate or get its message. Of course, `CustomException` must extend `Exception` to be throwable.

Comment: You should collapse the catch blocks. `catch(IOException | IllegalArgumentException | ... e) {}`

Comment: And you probably also mean to throw a new exception, not just create one.

Comment: Many typos occur if not using an IDE. Thanks :))